# Used numba to consume GPU instead of CPU in loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, cross-product

I have a list with multiply identities and each identity consists of multiple images. When i am retrieving positive images from json list it works fine. After that I am mixing this positive list with by doing cross product with every images in pair form and then save in negative array. When i am doing cross product, my system got completely hang even i have 16 GB RAM with GPU.

****Code****

```
for i in range(0, len(idendities) - 1):
    for j in range(i + 1, len(idendities)):
        # print(samples_list[i], " vs ",samples_list[j])
        cross_product = itertools.product(samples_list[i], samples_list[j])
        cross_product = list(cross_product)
        # print(cross_product)

        for cross_sample in cross_product:
            # print(cross_sample[0], " vs ", cross_sample[1])
            negative = []
            negative.append(cross_sample[0])
            negative.append(cross_sample[1])
            negatives.append(negative)

negatives = pd.DataFrame(negatives, columns=["file_x", "file_y"])
negatives["decision"] = "No"

negatives = negatives.sample(positives.shape[0])
```

Comment: How big is the size of your sample lists?

Comment: The size is 138368

Comment: Did this help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18390336/cartesian-product-memory-error-converting-itertools-product-to-list

Comment: Actually, Last time i tried to implement this answer but i stuck in coding. Could you please help me? Is it possible for you to give correct one answer on above code?

Answer (score 0):

Numba currently officially supports CUDA-enabled GPUs (AMD support still experimental). The official documentation/instructions to use Numba on GPUs is [here](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/cuda/index.html).

Depending on what exactly you want to do there are various details outlined in the webpage linked above but if you want to make your code run on the GPU in a simple way you can do something like this:

```
from numba import cuda

@cuda.jit(device=True):
def foo(a: int, b: int, c: int):
    return a * b + c #this can be whatever you want that is Numba compatible
```